# How to place an img on top of another img

Tags: html, css, image, href

I am trying to place one  on top of another at my website [finegra.in](http://www.finegra.in). Here is a screenshot of the site right now:

[image]

I just want the "visit our kickstarter project" img to go right here:
[image]

Here are the html and stylesheets:

```
<div id="page" class="hfeed">
    <header id="branding" role="banner">



            <!-- 
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
                <h3 class="assistive-text">Main menu</h3>
                                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to primary content">Skip to primary content</a></div>
                <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="Skip to secondary content">Skip to secondary content</a></div>
                                <div class="menu"><ul><li class="current_page_item"><a href="http://www.finegra.in/" title="Home">Home</a></li></ul></div>
            </nav><!~~ #access ~~>
 -->

            <hgroup>
            <div>
                <a href="http://www.finegra.in"><img id="logo" alt="fine grain Logo" src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/fineGRAINlogoGOOD-WEB.png">
</a>
<img id="headerimg" alt="The Sheffield Case" src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/headerimg2.jpg">
<a href="http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/finegrain/17408941?token=364cb635"><img id="branding" alt="The Sheffield Case" src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/checkOurProject.png">
</a>

            </div>
            <div id="site-generator">
                FineGrain LLC Copyright 2012. All Rights Reserved  
            </div>
        </hgroup>
    </header><!-- #branding -->
```

style.css:

```
#branding {
    border-top: 0px solid #BBBBBB;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DADAD2;
}

#headerimg {
    width: 30% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

#branding img {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: auto;
}

.one-column #page {
    max-width: 1500px;
}

.one-column #content {
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UtKbC/

CSS:

```
.visit_project {
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
    left: 400px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/finegrain/17408941?token=364cb635" class="visit_project"><img id="branding" alt="The Sheffield Case" src="http://www.finegra.in/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/checkOurProject.png">
</a>
```

It might be wiser to wrap the header image in it's own div and set the checkOurProject.png image to the absolute value based on that div wrapper.

Comment: Ok done, and good point about the separate div. Now I know this wasn't my question, but is there a way to get the "visit our kickstarter project" image to have a transparent background instead of the background color square behind it? It's a png with a transparent background

Comment: Did you save the image with a transparent background? png is the correct format to use.

Comment: Yes I did, that's why I think its weird that its behaving like that

Comment: Nevermind, I see that you did. in `#branding {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DADAD2;}` make it more exclusive so it doesn't include background color to the image.

Comment: I actually just decided to make it a ton easier by just combining the "visit our kickstarter project" and the header image into one png in photoshop. Thanks for the tips though and I'll know better next time. what do you think of the splash page anyways?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using jQuery, you may create the watermarks for your images at the DOM ready function and make theirs position absolute and calculated relative to the images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Watermark image, change the src with your image's url
    var watermark = '<img src="watermark.png" border="0" style="border:none; background-color:transparent; position:absolute; ';

    // Position relative to image inside:
    var insideTop = 20;
    var insideLeft = 50;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("img").each(function (ix, el) {
            var top = $(this).offset().top + insideTop;
            var left = $(this).offset().left + insideLeft;
            var imgWatermark = watermark + 'top:' + top + 'px; left:' + left + 'px;"/>';
            $("body").append(imgWatermark);
        });
    });

</script>
```

If you have images that will have the watermark and images that won't, add an attribute class="withWatermark" to the images that will have and replace the $("img") in the script with $(".withWatermark").

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" class="withWatermark" />
```

```
$(".withWatermark").each(function (ix, el) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this easily by simple css with the help of float :-

**CSS**

```
    #header {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/1nrC6.jpg");
    width:1040px;
    height:402px;
}

.logo {
    float:right;
    margin-top:200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<a href="#"><img class="logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/17oqa.png"border="0"/></a>
</div>
```

see the demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/UtKbC/6/